# How can I clone the same forked repo without destroying what I do till now?

Tags: git, github

My collaborator forked my repo, and now we have problems merging his commits.

How can he clone after forking without destroying his commits?

[What I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUznh.jpg) when I want to merge his pull request:

```
If you cannot merge a pull request automatically here, 
you have the option to resolve conflicts and perform a manual merge.
```

[And](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6UVp.jpg):

```
This branch has conflicts that must be resolved.
```

Comment: Your images aren't showing up at all. This is a good thing because images are a bad way to ask questions; see [ask].

Answer (score 1):

If a branch has conflict before merging, then the author must rebase said branch on top of your target branch (let's say your origina repository, main branch)

rebase: replay his own local branch on top of your target branch, then force push said local branch to his fork: that will update the PR (Pull Request) automatically, and there won't be any conflict: that is because any conflict would have been solved locally during the local rebase.

So, on his workstation:

```sh
cd /path/to/local/fork/clone
git remote add upstream https://srvn-nm/Twitter-Java.git
git fetch upstream
git switch Atbin
git rebase upstream/main
# resolve any conflict
git push --force
```